# Symfony2 Join table to get column from another table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm kind of new to MySQL and Doctrine,

I basically have two tables `User` and `Role` that goes something like this

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
|User                                  |   Role             |
|id    username    password    role    |   id    name       |
|1     testuser    something   1       |   1     ROLE_USER  |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I followed the tutorial on Symfony's website, but I don't really know how to get `name` from role in the User Entity.

Currently it is written like so:

[Role Entity](http://pastebin.com/GfnZmdb1)

[User Entity Snippet](http://pastebin.com/hnpvkrKm)

I honestly don't know if it is joining it correctly, any help would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

You have to read doctrine documentation. There is [description of OneToMany](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) relationship mapping.

So Role entity should contain only `$id` and `$name` field mappings, but User entity `$role` field should look like

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
 * @JoinColumn(name="role", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $role;
```

Comment: What does $role become actually? because I get this error now "$roles must be an array of strings, or RoleInterface instances, but got object." is $roles an instance of the object Role?

Edit: Okay figured it out it does return an object, thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup with Users and Roles except I use a ManyToMany relationship. After all, I think most applications will want to be able to assign more than 1 role to a user.

The associations need to be setup like the below. You'll need to create proper getter/setters for assigning roles to users, of course.

**User**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_roles",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 */
protected $roles;

public function __construct() {
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Role**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
 */
protected $users;

public function __construct() {
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The above would allow you use the roles like this:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->find($id);
print_r($user->getRoles()->toArray());
```